# I want to compare two projects in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, compare, diff

I have a couple Android Studio projects that are similar, and I want to know exactly where their source files differ.  What is an easy way to do that?

Comment: With `diff` you could do: `diff -urN project1 project2`.

Comment: I wish ... but I am on Windows.  And I want to compare only the source files (.java and .xml files). I guess I am asking whether there is a way to do it in Android Studio.

Answer (score 31):

Right click file/directory/project/module > click **compare with** > give the path to compare

EASY WAY TO FIND PATH : ( considering both projects are open in Android Studio)
Switch to project you want to compare > right click file/directory/project/module > **copy path** > paste it back in select path dialog.
BETTER to copy path first.

Verified : Android Studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 10):

**In Android studio 3.4.2** you can do by right click on

Select Android : **app → Compare Directories** select proper path for your files and done.

In **Android Studio Bumblebee :**   app → Compare With or Ctrl+D :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is such a lifesaver, I had taken a backup of my project and had made changes to fix an issue and also optimize and ended up with a failing app and since I kept making changes at different places needed to know what were the changes without wasting too much time

Answer (score 8):

I'm highly recommend **Compare Directories Plugin** for Android Studio 2+.

> Allows the fast comparison of two directories or archive files (jar,
>   zip, war... and also tar/gz) based on file contents. Compared
>   directories/archives are shown in a tree view to give a better and
>   easier-to-read overall view of the differences.

**Installation:**

Open: File > Settings > Plugins 
Click on the button “Browse repositories”, find the “Compare Directories” plugin in the available plugins list, right click on it and choose install.

[image: Compare Directories Plugin]

**General usage instructions:**

Execute the Compare Directories... menu command, select two directories or zip/jar/tar files containing files with the same file names and see the comparison results on the opened Compare Directories panel:

- Files and directories are shown depending on the differences in their
  contents: identical, different by blanks only, non-significantly
  different, different, left-only, right-only.
- Compared text file can be then edited within IDEA.
- Compared text file differences can be then viewed with the usual IDEA diff window.
- Compared class bytecode differences can be also viewed with the usual IDEA diff window.
- Files and directories can be copied from one side to the other.

You will find many more details in the plugin page:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/113-compare-directories